# How to write the result of a calculation in a Label?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I am trying to write out the result of a calculation in a label.

- Label ✓
- Positioning ✓
- `str.tostring()` ✓
- Only once. ✓ (No need for past values of the calculation.)

**Only the calculation is not processed.** Simplified code:

```
//@version=5

indicator(title="Calculation in Label", overlay=true)

var float CalculationToDisplay = ta.sma(close, 100) + 2

var label CalculationLabel = na
if(na(CalculationLabel))
    CalculationLabel := label.new(bar_index, ta.sma(close, 100), color=color.gray,  text=str.tostring(CalculationToDisplay) + 'abc', textcolor=color.white, style=label.style_label_left)
else
    label.set_x(CalculationLabel, bar_index + 2)
    label.set_y(CalculationLabel, ta.sma(close, 100))
```

**There's only a "NaN%" text in the label. The crucial point when the calculation collapses is the usage of that `ta.sma()` function. How to make it work?**
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You used `var` in this line:

```
var float CalculationToDisplay = ta.sma(close, 100) + 2
```

This line means "assign the SMA's **initial value** to `CalculationToDisplay`". Since `ta.sma(close, 100)` needs 100 bars to calculate, it will return `na` on the first bar, so you practically assigned `na` to `CalculationToDisplay`.

Remove the `var` and update your label text will solve the issue, i.e.

```
//@version=5

indicator(title="Calculation in Label", overlay=true)

float CalculationToDisplay = ta.sma(close, 100) + 2

var label CalculationLabel = na
if(na(CalculationLabel))
    CalculationLabel := label.new(bar_index, ta.sma(close, 100), color=color.gray,  text=str.tostring(CalculationToDisplay) + 'abc', textcolor=color.white, style=label.style_label_left)
else
    label.set_text(CalculationLabel, str.tostring(CalculationToDisplay) + 'abc')
    label.set_x(CalculationLabel, bar_index + 2)
    label.set_y(CalculationLabel, ta.sma(close, 100))
```

Read more about `var` here: https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v5/language/Variable_declarations.html#var